# Why The map from $Hom(R, M)$ into $M$ is uniquely determined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring. Let $M$ be an $R$-module. The map $\phi$ from the set of $R$-module homomorphisms from $R$ into $M$, that is,  $Hom(R, M)$ into $M$ is uniquely determined by $\phi(f)=f(1_R)$. Why is this map surjective? So, why for every element $m$ of $M$ we have an R-homomorphism $f$ such that $m=f(1_R)$. I cannot understand why $f(1_R)$ is any element in $M$ and not $1_MM$ since we have an homomorphism.

Would you help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "uniqeuly determined" is not the same as "surjective"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume $R$ is commutative and unital. (One just needs a little more care in the non-commutative case.)

Let's consider a module homomorphism $\phi: R\to M$. Then
$$\phi(r)=\phi(r1)=r\phi(1)$$
for all $r\in R$, as $\phi$ is an $R$-module homomorphism.
Therefore $\phi$ is completely determined by the value $\phi(1)$,
which is an element of $M$.

Given an element $m$ of $M$, we define $\phi_m:R\to M$ by
$$\phi_m(r)=rm.$$
Then it is routine to prove that $\phi_m$ is an $R$-module homomorphism,
and that $\phi_m(1)=m$. This shows that for each $m\in M$ there is
exactly one $R$-module homomorphism from $R$ to $M$ taking $1$ to $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m\in M$, defined $f(r)=rm$, you obtain the morphism. So $\phi$ is surjective, $\phi(f)=\phi(f')$ implies that $f(1_R)=f'(1_R)$, for every $r\in R$, you have $f(r)=f(r.1_R)=rf(1_R)=rf'(1_R)=f'(r)$ and $f=f'$ thus $\phi$ is injective.